# Can I use a <input type="hidden"> tag with resultSet to pass the values to servlet?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I am working on an application where I display a list of items and then provide an "CLICK TO BUY" button against each row. So, basically here is what the final application should look like:

ITEM_NUM::::ITEM_NAME::::ITEM_PRICE::::BUY?

1. ::::    MY_BOOK  :::: 2.99     :::: ADD TO CART
2. ::::    MY_BOOK2 :::: 9.99     :::: ADD TO CART
3. ::::    MY_BOOK3 :::: 10.99    :::: ADD TO CART

I am able to display this list correctly. However, I need to be able to click on ADD TO CART button for each row and then send the data for that row (i.e. item_num, name, price) to the Servlet function which will add the item to the cart. Here is the code that I am using:

```
try {
    Statement s1 = c1.createStatement();
    String q1 = "select itemNum, itemName, itemPrice from part_list";
    ResultSet rset = s1.executeQuery(q1);
    if (!rset.isBeforeFirst()) {
        out.println("<h3> No Items in inventory yet. Everything Sold Out!!!</h3>");
        out.println("</br>");
    } else {
    %>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Item Number </th>
            <th>Item Name </th>
            <th> Item Price </th>
            <th> BUY? </th>
        </tr>
        <form name="inventoryForm" action="cartserv" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="choice" value="addCart">
            <%

                out.println("<br/><br/>");

                while (rset.next()) {

                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<td>" + rset.getInt(1) + "</td><td>" + rset.getString(2) + "</td><td>" + rset.getDouble(4) + "</td><td>");
                    out.println("<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"CLICK TO BUY\"/></td>");
            %>
                    <input type="hidden" name="iPrice" value="<%=rset.getDouble(4)%>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="iName" value="<%=rset.getString(2)%>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="iNum" value="<%= rset.getInt(1)%>"
           <%
                out.println("</tr>");
                }
            %>

        </form>
    </table>
```

So my intent here was to use the hidden input types (names=iPrice, iName, iNum) to pass the info for each row to the servlet method. The fact that I am able to display these items correctly indicates that my while loop is working. But my problem is that if i click on ADD TO CART on the 3rd row (i.e. MY_BOOK3), it will still pass the information to the servlet for the first row only. It seems that once the value from first row data is assigned to these hidden variables, it is not getting updated for each row.

My question, therefore, is that how to passs item_name, item_num, item_price to the servlet corresponding to the row for which the ADD TO CART is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values on the next page. So if they click the button and it takes them to the shopping cart page, you can gather up all that information you would like.

Like this

```
$iPrice = $_POST['iPrice']
$iName = $_POST['iName']
$iNum = $_POST['iNum']
```

Then you can use those variables anywhere on the page.

Thanks,
Josh